# Do gains and losses across multiple different investments get netted at tax time? Or is the income tax applied individually for each?

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax

Lets say I have online brokerage A providing me with an individual (non-retirement) investment account. Call it X. I also have a Forex account, call it Y. If I make $500 in X, and -$300 in Y on the year do I owe that income tax as net $200? Or just on $500? What if it was absurd and was x=600 and Y=-4000? Would I still owe taxes on $600? I would imagine it has to be net, right?

Obviously ignoring the stuff like different tax brackets, short vs long term capital gains, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I make $500 in X, and -$300 in Y on the year do I owe that income tax as net $200? Or just on $500?

200 USD, assuming that you are talking about US taxes. See https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/062713/capital-losses-and-tax.asp ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927042539/https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/062713/capital-losses-and-tax.asp)):

> Any loss can be netted against any capital gain realized in the same tax year, but only $3,000 of capital loss can be deducted against earned or other types of income in the year. Remaining capital losses can then be deducted in future years up to $3,000 a year, or a capital gain can be used to offset the remaining carry-forward amount.